# Text filter on two types of queries

Tags: reactjs, arrays, list, text, filter

I want to Filter some events by text on the key_Value but also by name displayed

for that i made some if/else statements for the names :

```
box.descEvents.forEach((printEvent: PrintEvent) => {
    let printEventDisplay: string

    if (!printEvent) {
        return null
    }

    if (printEvent.name === 'interpass_ready') {
        printEventDisplay =
            `Part cooled down to ${printEvent.meta['interpass_temp']}°C ` +
            `in ${printEvent.meta['wait_time']}s`
    } else if (printEvent.name === 'chunk_init' || printEvent.name === 'chunk_done') {
        printEventDisplay = box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name)
        printEventDisplay += ' ' + (parseInt(printEvent.value) + 1).toString()
    } else if (printEvent.name === 'control_fault') {
        printEventDisplay = box.getStopLabel(printEvent.meta.reason) + ': '
    } else if (eventDenylist.includes(printEvent.name)) {
        return
    } else if (triggerSignals.includes(printEvent.name)) {
        printEventDisplay = box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name) + ' '
        if (printEvent.name === 'limit_switch') {
            printEventDisplay +=
                printEvent.value === 'True' || printEvent.value === true
                    ? 'released'
                    : 'triggered'
        } else {
            printEventDisplay +=
                printEvent.value === 'True' || printEvent.value === true
                    ? 'triggered'
                    : 'released'
        }
    } else if (openedSignals.includes(printEvent.name)) {
        printEventDisplay = box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name) + ' '
        printEventDisplay +=
            printEvent.value === 'True' || printEvent.value === true ? 'closed' : 'open'
    } else if (sourceSignals.includes(printEvent.name)) {
        printEventDisplay = box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name) + ' from '
        printEventDisplay += printEvent.meta['source'] ? printEvent.meta['source'] : 'unknown'
    } else if (printEvent.name == 'running') {
        printEventDisplay = 'Robot '
        printEventDisplay +=
            printEvent.value === 'True' || printEvent.value === true ? 'started' : 'stopped'
    } else if (printEvent.name == 'sync_calibration') {
        printEventDisplay = 'Sync calibration values '
        if (printEvent.value == 'request') {
            printEventDisplay += 'requested'
        } else if (printEvent.value == 'done') {
            printEventDisplay += 'finished'
        }
    } else {
        if (printEvent.name && printEvent.value !== null) {
            printEventDisplay =
                box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name) + ': ' + printEvent.value.toString()
        } else if (printEvent.name) {
            printEventDisplay = printEvent.name
        } else {
            console.dir(printEvent)
        }
    }
```

i made a local state to activate whenever textfield is used:

```
const [filterQuery, setFilterQuery] = React.useState('')

const getEventNames = box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name).split(',')

    if (filterQuery) {
        filteredList.push(
            <ul>
                {getEventNames
                    .filter((name) => name.toLowerCase().includes(filterQuery.toLowerCase()))
                    .map((name) => (
                        <div key={uuid4()}>
                            <AccordionItem
                                printEventDisplay={printEventDisplay}
                                printEvent={printEvent}
                                eventName={name ? ' (filtered event)' : null}
                                eventSource={eventSource ? eventSource : null}
                                eventID={eventID}
                                eventLineNumber={eventLineNumber}
                                printEventValue={printEventValue ?? ''}
                                checkColorToggle={checked}
                                clsxClass={
                                    checked
                                        ? clsx({
                                            [classes.accordionWarning]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'warning',
                                            [classes.accordionRunning]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'running' &&
                                                printEvent.value === false,
                                            [classes.accordionChunkStarted]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'chunk_init',
                                            [classes.accordionChunkDone]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'chunk_done',
                                            [classes.accordionControlFault]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'control_fault' &&
                                                printEvent.value === true,
                                            [classes.accordionTorchCollisionTriggered]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'torch_collision' &&
                                                printEvent.value === true,
                                            [classes.accordionRobotStarted]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'running' &&
                                                printEvent.value === true,
                                            [classes.accordionRobotStopped]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'running' &&
                                                printEvent.value === false,
                                            [classes.accordionTorchCollisionReleased]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'torch_collision' &&
                                                printEvent.value === false,
                                            [classes.accordionSafetyChainTriggered]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'safety_chain' &&
                                                printEvent.value === true,
                                            [classes.accordionInterpass]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'interpass_temp' &&
                                                printEvent.value &&
                                                printEvent.meta['interpass_temp'],
                                            [classes.accordionSafetyChainRelease]:
                                                printEvent.name === 'safety_chain' &&
                                                printEvent.value === false,
                                            [classes.accordionLimitSwitch]:
                                                (printEvent.name === 'limit_switch' &&
                                                    printEvent.value === 'True') ||
                                                printEvent.value === true,
                                        })
                                        : classes.accordionDefault
                                }
                                clsxText={''}
                                setColorToggle={toggleChecked}
                                eventList={undefined}
                                accordionItem={undefined}
                                printEventName={undefined}
                                scrollableDiv={undefined}
                            />
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </ul>
        )
    }
```

how do i make the query look for the printEventDisplay, instead of the printEvent.name?
can i use an OR operator or an AND after the fist query type?

Comment: Just use && or || and use brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a global state already including these names so i included it it in the variable:

```
const getEventNames = box.getNameLabel(printEventDisplay).split(',') || box.getNameLabel(printEvent.name).split(',')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).